# android fade-in error

Tags: android, fadein

Hi to all
I'm having a problem with this code. I'm trying to make the image fade-in. This is the eclipse error:

```
The method loadAnimation(Context, int) in the type AnimationUtils is not applicable for the arguments (new Runnable(){}, int)
```

This is my code:

```
Handler timerHandler = new Handler();
{
    Runnable loadImg2 = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {    
        DisplayTitle(gCursor);
        Bitmap bitmap2 = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(sdcard/image.jpg);
        myImageView=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageview1);
        (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.myImageView);
        Animation myFadeInAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fadein);
        myImageView.startAnimation(myFadeInAnimation);
        myImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap2);
        timerHandler.postDelayed(clearImg, 55000);//55000);
        "); 
    }  
};
```

Comment: can you confirm your post represents your code correctly? I just cleaned up the indentation to make sure I'm reading it correctly, but I see several things that I can't imagine compile, such as the line containing `clearImg after 5 sec ");` and `.decodeFile(sdcard/image.jpg);`.

Answer (score 5):

Try following code, it works for me....

```
Animation myFadeInAnimation =
    AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getapplicationContext, R.anim.fadein);
```

instead

```
Animation myFadeInAnimation =
    AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fadein);
```

maybe it will help you...

Answer (score 1):

It's a matter of scope.

It's not clear what your trying to do by putting your animation creation inside the Runnable, but in answer to your question the reason for the build failure is that the 'this' parameter in your loadAnimation() call refers to the Runnable object you are calling the function from within. There are other ways to refer to the outer object whose method you are within. For example, if the outer method is on a class called Foo, then you can say 'Foo.this' to refer to *that* instance instead of the Runnable instance this code is within.

Comment: ok can you please tell me how i can use the fade-in with this code

Comment: I can't say, because I don't understand what your code is trying to do. If you just want to fade in a view, then all of the Handler/Runnable stuff is unnecessary - just create an AlphaAnimation on the View. If you want it to start after some delay (like the 55000 value above, which seems a bit long...), then set the startOffset attribute appropriately.